# Why doesn't gets() take a char pointer argument if it can take a char array?

Tags: c, stdin, gets

Considering this code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char *s;
  gets(s);
  printf("%s",s);
  return 0;
}
```

I get a runtime error in this case after entering some input at `stdin`. However if `s` is declared as an array, `s[size]`, there is no issue. But considering the `gets` prototype, `char *gets(char *s);` shouldn't it work?

Comment: You haven't allocated any memory for `s` to point to.

Comment: `s = malloc(BUFSIZE);`

Comment: 1) Did you read the documentation? It **takes** a `char *`. 2) **never ever use `gets`** It has been removed from the standard and every modern library warns if you try to use it.

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gets` function expects `s` to point to a character array that can accept a string.  But in this case, `s` is uninitialized.  So `gets` tries to dereference an uninitialized pointer.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you were to set `s` to point to a preexisting array or if you used `malloc` to allocate space, then you can write to it successfully.

In contrast, if `s` is defined as an array, it decays to a pointer to the first element of the array when passed to `gets`.  Then `gets` is able to write to the array.

Note however that `gets` is unsafe because it makes no attempt to verify the size of the buffer you pass to it.  If the user enters a string larger than the buffer, `gets` will write past the end of the buffer, which again invokes undefined behavior.

You should instead use `fgets`, which accepts the size of the buffer as a parameter.